# Implementing pagination on modal in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pagination, modal-dialog, webgrid

On my mvc application the user can do search, I then store the result in a session then is displayed on a webgrid where my pagination works fine.

The issue is my advance search, which I implemented through a modal, the pagination does not work. Whenever I try to go to a different page it doesn't display anything.

This is what I have right now.

Controller

```
ActionResult Index(filter)

{

    //Retrieve data from regular search

    //Store in a session

    //return session

}

ActionResult GetRegularGrid()

{

    //retrieve regular search session

    //return same session

}

ActionResult AdvanceSearch(filter)

{

    //Retrieve data from advance search

    //store in a session

    //return advance search session to partial view

}
```

Index View

```
<script>              
               $(function () {                       
                   GetRegularGrid();                  
               });

               function GetRegularGrid() {
                   console.log();
                   $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: 'SearchController/GetRegularGrid',
                       success: function (response) {
                           $("#DataList").show();
                           $("#DataList").html(response);
                           $('#ASGrid').hide();
                       },
                       cache: false,
                       error: function (error) {
                           console.log(error);
                       }
                   });
<a href="#" style="font-weight: bold" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AdvSearch">Advance Search</a>

<br />
            <div class="modal fade" id="AdvSearch">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                        <p style="font-weight: bold" class="modal-title">Advance Search</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form id="AdvanceSearchForm">
                                @Html.Partial("AdvSearchForm")
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                    <td><p align="left">% accepts wildcard</p></td>
                                <td width="320px"></td>
                                <td><input type="button" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" id="ASearchbtn" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="ASGrid">

        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#ASearchbtn").click(function () {

                    var form = $('#AdvanceSearchForm');
                    var ASData = $('#AdvanceSearchForm').serialize();
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                    form.validate();

                    if (form.valid()) {
                        $("#ErrMsg").text("");
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/SearchController/AdvanceSearch",
                            data: ASData,
                            datatype: "html",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (response) {
                                $("#AdvSearch").modal("hide");
                                $('#ASGrid').html('');
                                $('#ASGrid').html(response);
                                $('#ASGrid').show();
                                $("#DataList").hide();
                                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                                $('#noresult').hide();                                    
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                $("#ErrMsg").text("Invalid search - Atleast one field is required.");
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {                          
                        $('tbody tr').hover(function () {
                            $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
                        }).on('dblclick', function () {
                            var sid = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
                            $("#subId").val(sid);
                        })

                        return false;
                    });

                    return false;
                });                    
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change POST to GET to fix this issue and it works now

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ASearchbtn").click(function () {

                var form = $('#AdvanceSearchForm');
                var ASData = $('#AdvanceSearchForm').serialize();
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                form.validate();

                if (form.valid()) {
                    $("#ErrMsg").text("");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/SearchController/AdvanceSearch",
                        data: ASData,
                        datatype: "html",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            $("#AdvSearch").modal("hide");
                            $('#ASGrid').html('');
                            $('#ASGrid').html(response);
                            $('#ASGrid').show();
                            $("#DataList").hide();
                            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                            $('#noresult').hide();                                    
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            $("#ErrMsg").text("Invalid search - Atleast one field is required.");
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
                }

                $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {                          
                    $('tbody tr').hover(function () {
                        $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
                    }).on('dblclick', function () {
                        var sid = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
                        $("#subId").val(sid);
                    })

                    return false;
                });

                return false;
            });                    
        });
    </script>
```